# Combining data into a single cell while summing a seperate cell

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't know how to word my question very well, so I will start with the data being returned:

prop_id | assessed_value | sale_id

35004 | 401200 | 1920831

35005 | 40500 | 1920831

35023 | 11300 | 1920831

34380 | 139100 | 1915846

127959 | 286400 | 1915882

I would like it to return:

prop_id | assessed_value | sale_id

35004, 35005, 35023 | 453000(Sum of the 3 parcels) | 1920831

34380 | 139100 | 1915846

127959 | 286400 | 1915882

So my main goal is to combine all the parcels on the sale_id field into a string, but only when a sale id has multiple prop_id, and then sum up the assessed value of all those.  This is the query I am using to get the first set of data...

```
select 
pv1.[prop_id],
pv1.[assessed_val],
ld1.[sale_id]
from dbo.land_detail as ld1     
join dbo.property_val as pv1 on 
pv1.[prop_id] = ld1.[prop_id] and
pv1.[prop_val_yr] = ld1.[prop_val_yr] and
pv1.[sup_num] = ld1.[sup_num]
left join dbo.sale as sale1 on  
sale1.[chg_of_owner_id] = ld1.[sale_id]
where   
pv1.[prop_inactive_dt] is null
order by sale_id, prop_id
```

prop_id is of data type INT
assessed_val is of data type numeric(14,0)
sale_id is of data type INT

Comment: Please post your "before" data in a consumable format. A picture of data isn't data.

Comment: Posting your raw data structure, along with what you would expect your result set to look like, would be very helpful.

Comment: this question has been asked so many times. Google "How to use STUFF" Function in mssql

Comment: What would your desired resultset look like?

Comment: Slight detour...if you care about the accuracy of your results you should stop littering your queries with that NOLOCK hint. It can and will return missing and/or duplicate rows, not to mention a whole list of other pretty spectacular things. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: Your data shows that you already have a Ratio value and your query still is computing it. Please provide your table structures, sample data and result.

Comment: Please mark this inquiry as already answered. TY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use WITH to create a temporary table then you can use STUFF() FOR XML PATH to concatenate the prop_id field into one row

```
WITH temp AS (
select pv1.[prop_id],
       pv1.[assessed_val],
       ld1.[sale_id],
       sale1.[sl_price],
       sale1.[sl_dt],
       (pv1.[assessed_val]/NULLIF(sale1.[sl_price],0) as Ratio
  from dbo.land_detail as ld1 with(nolock)
  join dbo.property_val as pv1 with(nolock)
    on pv1.[prop_id] = ld1.[prop_id]
   and pv1.[prop_val_yr] = ld1.[prop_val_yr]
   and pv1.[sup_num] = ld1.[sup_num]
  left join dbo.sale as sale1 with(nolock)
    on sale1.[chg_of_owner_id] = ld1.[sale_id]
 where sale1.sl_dt <= '04/30/16'
   and sale1.sl_dt >= '05/01/15'
   and pv1.[sub_type] = 'r'
   and pv1.[prop_val_yr] = 2016
   and pv1.[prop_inactive_dt] is null
 order by sale_id, prop_id
)

SELECT STUFF(( SELECT ', ' + CAST(prop_id AS VARCHAR)
                FROM temp
                WHERE sale_id = t.sale_id
                FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
                .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'') AS parcels,
       SUM(t.assessed_val) assessed_val,
       t.sale_id,
       t.sl_price,
       t.sl_dt,
       SUM(t.ratio) ratio
  FROM temp t
 GROUP BY t.sale_id,
          t.sl_price,
          t.sl_dt
 ORDER BY t.sale_id DESC
```

Comment: When I go to create the temp table it gives me this error:     Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Divide by zero error encountered.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: And when I try and execute the second part I get this error message:    Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ', ' to data type int.

Comment: I edited the code above to use WITH instead of INTO #temp. Can you provide your table structure to show the data type of each column. I think prop_id is of data type INT?

Comment: prop_id is of data type INT    assessed_val is of data type numeric(14,0)     and sale_id is of data type INT

Comment: I edited the SQL code to use CAST(prop_id AS VARCHAR)

Comment: I am now getting an error code of...  Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Divide by zero error encountered.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.         P.S.  Thank you so much for your help so far!

Comment: Divide by zero is encountered in getting the value for ratio from your original query. You may use NULLIF() like (pv1.[assessed_val]/NULLIF(sale1.[sl_price],0) as Ratio

Answer (score 0):

Put everything into a temp table (#temp) as below. Then make a self join to select the values. There are several ways of doing concatenation using (SUFF(), XML PATH, etc). Search on the internet on how to concatenate rows into comma separated string refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string) link for example

```
select 
pv1.[prop_id],
pv1.[assessed_val],
ld1.[sale_id],
sale1.[sl_price],
sale1.[sl_dt],
(pv1.[assessed_val]/sale1.[sl_price]) as Ratio
--------Temp Table------------
INTO #temp
------------------------------
from dbo.land_detail as ld1 with(nolock)    
join dbo.property_val as pv1 with(nolock) on    
pv1.[prop_id] = ld1.[prop_id] and
pv1.[prop_val_yr] = ld1.[prop_val_yr] and
pv1.[sup_num] = ld1.[sup_num]
left join dbo.sale as sale1 with(nolock) on 
sale1.[chg_of_owner_id] = ld1.[sale_id]
where   
sale1.sl_dt <= '04/30/16' and
sale1.sl_dt >= '05/01/15' and
pv1.[sub_type] = 'r' and
pv1.[prop_val_yr] = 2016 and
pv1.[prop_inactive_dt] is null
order by sale_id, prop_id
```